# How to decode a ternary Golay code? Any example will work.

Tags: coding-theory

How to decode a received Golay code? There are some algorithms but the article doesn't include any examples.
[image]

Comment: I'm sure there is an easier method for doing this by hand, but I'm afraid I don't recall having ever seen one. If I had to do this a lot (say, in a computer simulation) I would just write a look-up-table of all the possible 243 syndromes together with the associated coset leaders.